# Ошибка цвета. Python3 tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Все работает так:

Загружаю из файла в массив данные:

```
file = open( user + "\.clicker.save",'r') 
text = file.readlines()
file.close()

custom.insert(0,text[0])
custom.insert(1,text[1])
```

(В файла данные - black,gray95)

Затем хочу использовать данные как цвета:

```
def cus(fg,bg):
    lbl.configure(bg=bg, fg=fg)
    clickb.configure(bg=bg, fg=fg, activebackground=bg)
    shop.configure(bg=bg, fg=fg,activebackground=bg)
    clear.configure(bg=bg, activebackground=bg)
    window.configure(bg=bg)

cus(custom[0],custom[1])
```

Но выдает ошибку что цвета не найдены, хотя все они есть в tkinter.

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clicker.py", line 279, in <module>
    cus(custom[0],custom[1])
  File "clicker.py", line 189, in cus
    lbl.configure(bg=bg, fg=fg)
  File "D:\python382\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1637, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "D:\python382\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1627, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "black
"
```

Что делать?

Comment: Посмотрите, что выводит ошибка. Вы можете заметить, что в конце ошибки идёт переход на новую строку в названии "black", а цвета с названием "black\n" не существует. Появляется новая строка из-за того, что readlines() их не убирает, это надо делать самому.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в том, что метод readlines в конце каждой строки возвращает символ новой строки - '\n'. Исправить это можно так:
`text = [i.rstrip('\n') for i in file.readlines()]`